# Low quality delphi user interface design under Android when using TImage

Tags: android, delphi, image-processing, firemonkey

Since Android phones are released in many different screen resolutions and my user interface is "skinned" using multiple TImage components, I've hit a major development issue, I must scale each of my images relative to the device's screen resolution.

For some reason which I can not understand, under Android, TImage is interpolated using a really low quality scaler (possibly nearest-neighbor), resulting in a very low quality image display (this happens even when the screen scale is taken into consideration and the form's quality is set the high).

Due to this, it means I can either pre-scale and include multiple different resolutions of the same image, hoping that it will look 'close enough' (and bloating my app), or I can use a software algorithm to scale the images in real-time and then cache the result for later runs.

I choose the second option, using a software bicubic scaler, but the problem is that my app has so many image resources, it can take 18 seconds to load the first time on a high end mobile device.

I'm aware it may be possible to do what I need in hardware using OpenGL, but I haven't been able to find a clear/clean example of how this can be done in Delphi for Android.  And even if it can be done without having to re-code the entire UI for OpenGL.

Is there something I'm missing design wise?
Is a fix from Embarcadero my only chance?

Comment: Scale the images on demand so that you don't take that 18s hit in one go. And look for more efficient scaling code.

Comment: I tried that approached, but then there's an unusually long delay when opening some dialogs for the very first time, it makes the app feel sluggish, which is the wrong first impression.  I hand optimized the scaling code, I don't think it can be any faster without using ASM and that's not an option for Android. I was hoping for a hardware solution as every GPU supports this, it's just that delphi isn't utilizing the hardware

Comment: The standard way to go is to provide images of different sizes. I think you should use TImageList, load the images and then use Glyph or TImage with manual assignment of the image

Comment: I would not be at all surprised if there weren't software libraries that were much more efficient that the code you wrote. I mean, it's possible to write efficient code without resorting to assembler. Often algo choice and implementation are very important. Perhaps you have written optimal code, but perhaps not.

Comment: @JohnKouraklis I raised that as an option, but you can't just include enough resolutions to cover every device out, not to mention it bloats the application.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I searched high and low for a high quality (bicubic/lanczos) and only found one pure pascal implementation that I painstakingly optimized. I didn't even find commercial libraries that would work in Android using Delphi. If there are other options, I haven't found them.  The only thing that came up was using OpenGL and GPU hardware, but the code referred to was a massive library that I couldn't find a clean way to detach just the relevant code.

Comment: @bLight you can't have it all sadly. I still think the use of an algorithm generates serious overhead to an app that images are not its core business (or...are you writing an app what manipulates images?). You will consume cpu/gpu power for every image you have be it a small image in one button in the four form or not. You don't need to include that many resolutions. Even for this, there are some scale factors that become common

Comment: Have you compared the performance of your library with the best platform native libraries?

Comment: @JohnKouraklis I only scale the images once using the high quality software scaler, then the images are cached so the performance hit is only on the first load, but I'm trying to reduce load time and complexity by hoping to find a real-time GPU (hardware) scaler code.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan How can I do that? I couldn't find a single library that I can access on Android through Delphi that would let me do this.

Comment: Not through Delphi. Using the platform native dev tools. Scaling a handful of images should not be taking seconds. That sounds very wrong.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan If the scaling was done in hardware, it would have taken a second, but since it's software based, bicubic interpolation is somewhat computationally heavy. I'm not sure how I can use the native platform dev tools, I'm only familiar with Delphi programing. And I have no way of knowing if these dev tools are hooking into the GPU and doing it all in hardware. I've actually optimized beyond what can be done with an external library, I've actually extracted the weight distribution into a separate function so some math wont have to be re-calculated if multiple images are the same size

Comment: Doesn't sound very plausible to me. Anyway, I'm through.

Comment: I suggest you post your intgerpolation code and ask how to speed it up. I bet you use an inefficient algorithm. You can hand-tune an inneficient algorithm all you want, it will still be slow.

Comment: "under Android, TImage is interpolated using a really low quality scaler" I cannot reproduce that. There is almost zero information here that could help us in giving you some answers. How large images you have, how are you scaling them from which size to which size, code you use, Android API, do you see problem on multiple devices... anything. No matter what the real issue here is, writing your own scaling algorithm on Android is completely wrong solution.

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar You can see sample images and the difference in quality on this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51157715/low-quality-downscale-interpolation-when-using-a-gpu-canvas-and-tcanvas-drawbitm - The problem is not specific to Android, it's specific to Delphi with a GPU canvas (which is always the case when coding for Android using Delphi).  Note the difference in the small icons. Here is the code I used https://github.com/bLightZP/ImageInterpolation

Comment: @CrisLuengo I posted a link to the interpolation source code in the comment above this one. The StretchResampleInteger/MapIntegerStretchResample functions contain the optimized code.  It supports several algorithms, In my case bicubic interpolation is what I'm using.

Comment: This question is basically the duplicate of your last one. And has even less information. Your last question is also bad one, because there is also no information about what exactly are you doing. That is also why you didn't get appropriate answers. This is also why you will not get appropriate answer on this question.

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar You can easily reproduce my problem. Take a 256x256 bitmap (preferably of a "grid" that will alias badly if low quality interpolation is in use) and display it in a 172x172 TImage under android or under windows using a GPU canvas.  You should easily notice the aliasing. I'm trying to find a solution that will give me high-quality interpolation (similer to bicubic) and would hopefully be hardware based or more optimized than I could make it so that the user experience wont suck either by the slow load time or the bad image quality which are my current two options.

Comment: @bLight You missed the point of my comment. You should edit your question(s) and add more details.

Comment: Scaling is complex matter. In addition to the fact that not all images scale equally well, scale ratio matters. Without the doubt scaling image from 256 to 172 pix, will mostly give bad results.

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar Yes, that's why it's best performed using GPU hardware in real time, something Delphi is not doing even though it's using GPU hardware... This is the reason I'm trying to find a work-around that is Delphi+Android compatible that will allow me to use the GPU hardware to scale one TBitmap to another TBitmap with quality that is at least bicubic.

Comment: It would be helpful to provide screenshots of your application in your question. My important question is: Is your architectural approach good enough? Why you don't use vector graphics? We don't know because you didn't provide enough details. IF your application is the same like you provided in link as Oct 28 at 1:22 then ... i think that is the perfect candidate for vector graphics.

Comment: @mojmir.novak This is not about a particular application, it's about resizing images quickly using a good quality algorithm (preferably using hardware). I am aware of vector graphics, they do not fit into my design, but the sample images I posted in the Oct 28 at 1:22 link show the low quality scaler Delphi uses by default in it's GPU canvas, even though every GPU released in the last 10 years supports a higher quality option. It's just not accessible in Delphi by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It took me a while to lock this down, but here is Android native code that will scale the image in high quality much faster than any pure software solution I could find and optimize:

```
uses Androidapi.JNI.Media, Androidapi.JNI.GraphicsContentViewText, Androidapi.JNIBridge, FMX.Surfaces, FMX.Helpers.Android;

procedure AndroidResizeBitmap(srcBitmap,dstBitmap : TBitmap);
var
  sJBitmap     : JBitmap;
  ScaledBitmap : JBitmap;
  sSurface     : TBitmapSurface;
begin
  sSurface     := TBitmapSurface.Create;
  sSurface.Assign(srcBitmap);
  sJBitmap     := TJBitmap.JavaClass.createBitmap(sSurface.Width,   sSurface.Height,TJBitmap_Config.JavaClass.ARGB_8888);
  SurfaceToJBitmap(sSurface, sJBitmap);
  ScaledBitmap := TJBitmap.JavaClass.createScaledBitmap(sJBitmap,   dstBitmap.Width, dstBitmap.Height, True);
  sJBitmap     := nil;
  JBitmapToSurface(ScaledBitmap,sSurface);
  ScaledBitmap := nil;
  dstBitmap.Assign(sSurface);
  sSurface.Free;
  sSurface     := nil;
end;
```